# Передача html из файла в node-crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, cheerio

Прошу помощи в следующей ситуации. Парсер (на node-crawler https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler) должен обрабатывать не только http, но и локальные файлы. 
Не получается загрузить html через переменную. 
То что **работает** ниже (html в качестве явной строки):

```js
var Crawler = require("crawler");
var fs = require('fs'); 


var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, res, done) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            var $ = res.$;
            // $ is Cheerio by default
            //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
           
            console.log($("p").text());
        }
        done();
    }
});


c.queue([{
    html: '<p>Эта строка загружается и краулится</p>'
}]);
```

А вот **загрузка из файла в переменную не работает** (предпоследняя строка - это не работает) -

```js
var Crawler = require("crawler");
var fs = require('fs'); 


var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, res, done) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            var $ = res.$;
            // $ is Cheerio by default
            //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
        
            console.log($("p").text());
        }
        done();
    }
});

var htmlfromfile;


fs.readFile('htmldata.txt', "utf8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  htmlfromfile = data;
  
});



c.queue([{
    html: htmlfromfile
}]);
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: fs.readFile('htmldata.txt', "utf8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  htmlfromfile = data;
  console.log(htmlfromfile);
});

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
fs.readFile('htmldata.txt', "utf8", function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  htmlfromfile = data;
  c.queue([{
    html: htmlfromfile
  }])
});
```

Или используйте промис, так как c.queue может пытаться парсить htmlfromfile, когда тот ещё пока undefined.